# NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject Loop Leakage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I've edited the previous post with some working code for convenience.

The follow code (ARC'ed) seems to leak and will crash the sim or the device after running for a short period of time:

```
#define kROWS 100
#define kCols 34

void run();

static ViewController *instance;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *nsBackColor;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.nsBackColor = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    instance = self;

    // set up a '2D array'
    for (int x = 0; x < kROWS; x++) {
        [self.nsBackColor addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1]];
        for (int y = 0; y < kCols; y++) {
            [[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] addObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        run();
    });
}

- (void)plotColor:(UIColor *)color atX:(short)x andY:(short)y {
    [[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:color];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

void plot(short xLoc, short yLoc,
              short backRed, short backGreen, short backBlue) {

    @autoreleasepool {
        [instance plotColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)backRed/100)
                                            green:((float)backGreen/100)
                                             blue:((float)backBlue/100)
                                            alpha:(float)1]
                        atX:xLoc andY:yLoc];
    }
}

void run() {
    short x = 0;
    short y = 0;
    short backRed = 0;
    short backGreen = 0;
    short backBlue = 0;

    while (true) {
        x++;
        if (x >= kROWS) {
            x = 0;
        }

        y++;
        if (y >= kCols) {
            y = 0;
        }

        backRed = arc4random() % 255;
        backBlue = arc4random() % 255;
        backGreen = arc4random() % 255;

        plot(x, y, backRed, backGreen, backBlue);

        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If I let this run on the device or the simulator long enough (a couple minutes) I'll receive either an mmap malloc error (sim) or a memory warning (device) and crash.

Going through Instruments Allocations I can see +[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:] start to ballon until finally hitting the memory wall.

I can assign the UIColor to a property (directly or by doing a copy), say self.myColor = color, and there is no such leak.

I can do this too:

```
[[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:[self description]];
```

and I get the same leak.

It seems to me that object replaced in the array (and yes, this did originally start as a 2D c array but I thought that was the issue) is forever lost and leaked and not properly released.

This would be the Instruments->Allocations after running for a short period of time:

[image: Instruments]

Any help would be much appreciated and more information can be provided.

Comment: Have you looked at this in Instruments to confirm your suspicions about the leak?

Comment: You bet. Added an image.

Comment: When does the main runloop get a chance to drain the autorelease pool? Will `usleep` allow this or will the `while (true)` prevent the main runloop from clearing the autorelease pool?

Comment: Excellent point. If you break point and check the run() method loop it runs on Thread 2 (Thread 2, Queue : com.apple.root.default-priority) and so does the call to plotColor. Adding a dispatch to run on the main thread:

- (void)plotColor:(UIColor *)color atX:(short)x andY:(short)y {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:color];
    });
}

Results in the same memory leak. Also, setting a property strong in this loop on Thread 2 never creates the leak I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are creating an autorelease pool at every iteration.
So the following line runs every time with a new autorelease pool:

```
[[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:color];
```

Therefore `color` increases its reference count within the local pool by one, while `[[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y]` decreases its reference count within the local pool by one. But here's the catch: That item was `color` in the previous iteration, which had its reference count managed by the previous pool that you drained/released earlier.

So what should have happened is as the previous pool was released in the previous iteration, that object was released. Its reference count was 2 (one for `[UIColor colorWith...]`, one for adding to the array), so it should have received 2 release messages as soon as the pool was drained, and the pointer in `[[self.nsBackColor objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y]` should be left dangling until you replace it in the current iteration with a pointer to `color`.

Clearly that's not happening exactly the way it's supposed to be, or the way I understand it. However, the `@autoreleasepool {}` directive is clearly misplaced. It should be around the `while (true)` loop, or removed altogether in favor of the thread's pool.